# MDIWindowListITem Not Working

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

This one has really got me stumped. I have certain forms that are being instantiated. When I instantiate a form i make it a child of the mdi form by

form1.MdiParent = this;

I have set the MDIWindowListITem property of my menustrip to a toolstripmenuitem

However this toolstripmenuitem does not show the mdi child form when it is instantiated

Does any one have any ideas on this?

Any inputs/ leads / hints would be most welcome. I am using .net framework 3.5

Regards

,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write your code so that it is added manually I believe.

See the example here for pointers:

[MSDN help on ToolStripPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstrippanel.aspx)

***Edit***

You're right **ignore my previous entry** here's the code for a very simple MDI app that appears to do what your after.

It is just two blank forms. Form1 has `IsMDIContainer=true`. It also has `menuStrip1`, which contains two items "new" (`newToolStripMenuItem`) and "windows" (`windowsToolStripMenuItem`). Clicking new will open a new child window. I have set the `MDIWindowListItem` of `menuStrip1` to `windowsMenuStripItem`. When a new child window is opened clicking on `windowsMenuStripItem` produces a drop down that shows all windows open.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private int count;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void newToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            count++;
            //Set a window title text as this is what is shown in the window list.
            Form2 newForm = new Form2() { Text = string.Format("Window {0}", count) };
            newForm.MdiParent = this;
            newForm.Show();//<--- this needed to show window in list.
        }
    }
}
```

There is no code in Form2.

The child windows only show below `windowMenuStripItem` once Form.Show() has been called.
Without this they do not show in the list.

Comment: Hi 

Thanks! But I don't think that is required. Just setting the MDIWindowListitem property of the menustrip control should be enough. The designer should take care of the rest.

but anyway thanks for your inputs. I will go through the MSDN link you sent to me

Comment: @bornagaindeveloper - I've popped up some code. You need to make sure that your MDI child windows have their Text value set as this is what is displayed in the drop down list. Also they do not appear until their Show() method has been called.